# SharePoint 365: Change Lookup Column to Render HTML

Tags: jslink

In a Document Library I have a workflow that  make a link to the document in a library

for example

```
<a href="https:/xxxx/label/GFN1671-01.pdf" target="_blank"> GFN1671-01 </a>
```

In a List I have a lookup field that show this content in the list view.

Can I use JavaScript or JSLink to render this html code?

Comment: Post how the content will be listed in the list. Also on what format you want to display using JavaScript.